# how to make columns the same width with css flex

Tags: css

hello I need to basicaly display a table but with flex (only because I need to adjust the look for mobile)

.container {
display: flex
}

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>1000</div>
        <div>mary</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>john</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>11</div>
        <div>mike</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

how can I make each column have the same width? or at least the width of the largest item.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply `flex-grow: 1` to each div in the .row then it will expand accordingly. Note that the .row divs need the display flex (flex only apply to the DIRECT children of the flexed element.

The width can be set by using `flex-basis` and  `calc()` and dividing the full-width by the number of columns you want (2 in this case). I added a border to demonstrate.

I would be remiss if I didn't suggest that the best tool to display a table structure - is a ... table... then you can work out how to modifiy for responsive layout - but the semantic structure of a table is correct for tabulr content.

```css
.container { 
width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}


.row div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>1000</div>
        <div>mary</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>john</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>11</div>
        <div>mike</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I need to know in advance how many columns right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-basis` to set the 'default' width first.

Use `flex-grow` and/or `flex-shrink` to allow it to grow /shrink

Use `max-width' and` min-width` to define by how much it can grow/shrink

```
.container{ #Stack the div inside the conainer
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: columns nowrap;
}
.row{ # Set div as cell in the row.
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 flex-basis: 33%; # Calculate width from there.
 flex-grow:1; #Allow resizing bigger
flex-shrink:1; #Allow resize smaller.
max-width:50%; #Adjust to your liking
min-width:25%; #Adjust o your liking

}
```

Please consider this ressource https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: If need a column for table for three column, need a `flex-wrap: wrap` then `justify-content`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flex-basis to the .row items by doing this:

```
    .row {
        flex-basis:calc(100% / 3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container { 
width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}


.row div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
  padding:10px;
    
  margin: 5px;  
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>1000</div>
        <div>mary</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>john</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>11</div>
        <div>mike</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: hey Jone thx for your contribution. issue with this is that is causing all the columns to have the same width and for example the column id should be very short no need to keep it that long